# How to import public key from id_rsa.pub file

Tags: c#, public-key-encryption, ssh-keys

I have generated public & private key on windows using ssh-keygen util.

Now, I'm trying to use generated public key to encrypt a message. But I can't find how to import public key.
I tried (following suggestion from https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31091):

```
var rsaPublicKey = @"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";
using var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(Convert.FromBase64String(rsaPublicKey), out var _);
```

It keeps failing with

> ASN1 corrupted data

How do I import the public key, so I can use `RsaCryptoServiceProvider` to encrypt messages ?

Just in case this is `id_rsa.pub` file content:

> ssh-rsa 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 domain\mike-912789

Comment: I believe it needs to be converted. See [this](http://blog.oddbit.com/post/2011-05-08-converting-openssh-public-keys/).

Comment: Easiest way around this might be generating key in the expected format right away (I think it's done by providing "-m pem" parameter to ssh-keygen). Then import public key via `rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey()`)

Comment: Thank you both, indeed generating .pem format solved the issue.

Comment: I have this exact same issue, however I already did create my key with "-m pem".  My public key file and string look like Mike's as well.
I have tried `.ImportFromPem()` and `.ImportRSAPublicKey()` with and without the ssh-rsa start.  No luck.